# Перенос строки в сообщении от бота Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot

Как перенести строку в сообщении от бота?

Нужен результат в чате у пользователя

```
Hello
How
```

Запрос:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={CHAT_ID}&text=HelloHow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно получиться: `https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={CHAT_ID}&text=Hello\r\nHow`

Comment: я бы предложил всё же не `\n` а `%2F`

Answer (score 1):

В URL используйте [кодирование процентами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F), чтобы передавать расширенный набор символов. Для этого в большинстве популярных библиотек HTTP есть специальные функции. Например, [urllib.parse.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) в Python, [URLEncoder.encode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) в Java и пр. Воспользуйтесь ими. Если вы пишете простенький скрипт для себя, а текст сообщения никогда не меняется, вы можете ради упрощения заранее закодировать его с помощью [какого-либо онлайн ресурса](https://www.design-sites.ru/utility/url-encoding.php).